# Get bootstrap modal content from another cshtml view file in Visual Studio

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, razor, bootstrap-modal

In visual Studio I have a view that has a Bootstrap modal in it. I want to move that modal content in to another  View file of cs-html.

I know that there is a way to load the content on another HTML file. But I want to load the content of a View.cshtml in to a bootstrap modal in a separate cs-html view. can anyone suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Could you please post related code here..

Comment: Dear @GuruprasadRao If I add the code here the question will be harder to understand. I just want to know if there is a way or not to move my bootstrap modal code in the visual studio in to a separate cs-html View file and display the content.

Comment: Yes there are ways.. But we need to know what you know and what you actually what to know..

Comment: Dear @GuruprasadRao Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. the problem were with the link I have given in href. now I changed it comparing with the browser link and worked. Thanks again for your help. I am the one who have done the mistake here. sorry for all the trouble I made.

Comment: Anyways.. You found solution to you problem.. Happy to know that.. But as part of suggestion I would like to tell you that a good question in SO will always contain necessary code and helps people to help you.. :) Happy coding..

Comment: Thanx @GuruprasadRao.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here the problem were with the link I have given in href when calling the cshtml modal content. Instead of drag and drop I gave the link from the browser then the modal content showed(with some errors of course). don't trust the Drag and drop content all the time.

Cheers.